# error: spc0027: No relationship found among attributes in grid 'mygrid'

Tags: genexus

Hope some1 can help.

I copied this grid from another WP and seems like its not working. No clue why. Checked all I can but it doesnt work. In the other WP it works properly with another grids.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should improve the description of your question. Also something seems missing: what grid?

Answer (score 0):

Check the columns in the new grid. Does it have the same attributes than the source grid?

If you copied them from a different KB, it is highly possible that the attributes does not keep the same...

Comment: thanks for the response. 
No, they come from same KB. 
Copied entire grid, group included.
On the grid I copied from it used to load like :"Event gvRelacionProcesos.Load....."
but I don´t have a clear idea how this works where it calls it..Another mate made it.

Answer (score 0):

The specifier tries to find to which table the attributes belong. Don't think 'it should work because I copied it from a working wkp' , instead think 'some attribute is messing the specification' and take one by one out until it works, check if the obtained table is the desired one or another one. If it is the desired one, then the last attribute you withdrew is the one messing up the specification process. If it is another table than the desired one, try to withdraw from the grid the remaining attributes and put the ones you withdrew before back into the grid, and repeat the process. At some point you will understand which one is messing up. Also keep in mind that there might be other places with attributes, such as in the 'Load Event', they also influence the process.

Comment: thanks for the response. I also tried to create from scratch a grid with few fields and didn´t work. I dont have a clear Idea why it doens´t work.

Comment: tell me if you find something wrong:

I created a new grid, selected a field from the menu, clicked OK.

Defined following event:
event Grid1.Load
endevent

same error raises.

Answer (score 0):

It means that Genexus can not resolve the base table, you may be using (or referencing) attributes of different transactions and genexus can not resolve the relationship between them.